# Media query needed for text on hover

Tags: css

I would like to add a media query to adjust the font size for text that appears when hovering on an image. Can someone help, please?

This is code I am using in Divi for WordPress. I don't know where to add the media query.

Here is the code I am using. It works well on desktop, but the font is too big on mobile.

```
.pa-image-hover-text-one .et_overlay.et_pb_inline_icon:before {
    content: "Text goes here";
    font-family: Open Sans !important;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 28px;
    line-height: 1.3em;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 80%;
}
```

Comment: Want to [give it a shot](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp) first?

Comment: please include all your code including html

Comment: I am using the Divi theme for WordPress and added this CSS to the Custom CSS box. I haven't coded the website. I don't know where to put the media query.

Comment: @kimberly use the same css box to put ur media query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to do something like this:

```
.pa-image-hover-text-one .et_overlay.et_pb_inline_icon:before {
    content: "Text goes here";
    font-family: Open Sans !important;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 20px; /* CHANGE THIS TO WHATEVER YOU WANT */
    line-height: 1.3em;
    text-align: center;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    margin-left: 0px;
    width: 80%;
}


@media (min-width: 981px) {
    .pa-image-hover-text-one .et_overlay.et_pb_inline_icon:before {
        font-size: 28px;    
    }
}
```

Paste that into the Custom CSS box in the Divi settings. What this does is sets all of the styles for ALL viewport styles, then uses a `media` query to set the font larger above `981px`. You can change that to whatever you want. I believe the next break point down for Divi is `768px` and then `576px`.